# Office js Add-in compatibility

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I have recently developed an Add-in for my company using the Word API. It works perfectly on my machine using Word 2016.

My question is, will this Add-in work for older Word versions (2003 or newer )?

If not is there a work around this, or how to rewrite one that works for all version starting from 2003?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office.js was launched with Office 2013 for Windows. It is not supported on any versions prior to Office 2013 for Windows (or Office 2016 for Mac).

WordApi is a more recent addition. This API is only supported by Word 2016 for Windows/Mac, Word for iPad and Word Online.

You can find the supported hosts and platforms at [Office Add-in Availability](https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability).

With regards to your question on a workaround, there isn't any workarounds for leveraging Office.js with legacy/unsupported versions of Office.

Comment: do you know of an alternative solution other than Office.js ?

Comment: For working across Office platforms? There isn't one. You can use COM/VSTO but it is a legacy framework and limited to Office for Windows only.